# Loading Dataset gives error: Source XML is incomplete or invalid

Tags: xml, vba, dataset

I am getting an error when I load a DataSet from a file in VBA.

?RsLoadFromXML("c:\sletmig\test.xml")

Recordset cannot be created. Source XML is incomplete or invalid.

Here is my source code

```
    Function RsLoadFromXML(sPath As String) As Recordset
    Dim oStream As ADODB.Stream, oRsLoad As ADODB.Recordset

    On Error GoTo ErrFailed

    Set oRsLoad = New ADODB.Recordset
    oRsLoad.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    Set oStream = New ADODB.Stream
    oStream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
    oStream.Open
    'Load stream
    oStream.LoadFromFile sPath

    'Open recordset using stream
    oRsLoad.Open oStream
    Set RsLoadFromXML = oRsLoad

    oStream.Close
    Set oStream = Nothing
    Set oRsLoad = Nothing

    Exit Function

ErrFailed:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Debug.Assert False
    Set RsLoadFromXML = Nothing
End Function
```

trying to load this test.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Instruments>
<Control>
<AnalysisNotional>1000000</AnalysisNotional>
<TAsOf>18/08/2011</TAsOf>
<NumberOfDays>1</NumberOfDays>
</Control>
</Instruments>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure ADO can't be used to convert any random XML into a recordset: it has to be an XML file which was originally created by saving an existing ADO recordset to file...

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Williams is correct... the XML that ADO can handle is specifically for persistent recordsets created by Recordset.Save ([see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681501%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)).

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263247) from Microsoft can be misleading if you miss the fine print: *"Provided the XML data is in the format where ADO recordset can accept."*

If you want to load a generic XML file, use Microsoft XML (In Office you will need to add a reference to "Microsoft XML #.#". You can do this in Tools->References in the Visual Basic editor.)

```
Sub XML()
    Dim oDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set oDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    oDoc.Load ("C:\Path\To\File\AnXMLFile.xml")
End Sub
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

**EDIT**: You learn something new every day. This is actually pretty cool IMHO. Since you need the data in a recordset, you can create a recordset with no backing database and add data to it. ([Source article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260348%28v=vs.60%29.aspx))

```
Sub XML()
    Dim oDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim oSubNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMSelection

    Set oDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    oDoc.Load ("C:\Path\To\File\AnXMLFile.xml")

    Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set oRS.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    oRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    oRS.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic


    With oRS.fields
        .Append "AnalysisNotional", adInteger
        .Append "TAsOf", adDate
        .Append "NumberOfDays", adInteger
    End With

    oRS.Open

    For Each oNode In oDoc.selectNodes("/Instruments/Control")
        oRS.AddNew
        oRS.fields("AnalysisNotional").Value = oNode.selectSingleNode("AnalysisNotional").Text
        oRS.fields("TAsOf").Value = oNode.selectSingleNode("TAsOf").Text
        oRS.fields("NumberOfDays").Value = oNode.selectSingleNode("NumberOfDays").Text
    Next

    oRS.MoveFirst

    '--- Do something with recordset here ---
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I tried to create some sample code and the XML seems strange, so I will try your suggestion.

```
Sub Create_recordset()
    Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strFileName As String

    strFileName = "d:\sletmig\test.txt"


    Set r = New ADODB.Recordset

    'Add Columns
    r.Fields.Append "Field1", adVarWChar, 50
    r.Fields.Append "Field2", adVarWChar, 50

    'Create Recordset
    r.Open

    'Add rows into recordset
    r.AddNew Array("field1", "field2"), Array("string1", “val1”)
    r.AddNew Array("field1", "field2"), Array("string2", “val2”)

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill strFileName

    r.Save strFileName, adPersistXML

    r.Close
    Set r = Nothing

End Sub
```

give me this xml file

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:updatable='true'>
        <s:AttributeType name='Field1' rs:number='1' rs:write='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='50' rs:precision='0' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Field2' rs:number='2' rs:write='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='50' rs:precision='0' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <rs:insert>
        <z:row Field1='string1' Field2=''/>
        <z:row Field1='string2' Field2=''/>
    </rs:insert>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Comment: Here is a link to some nice code [link](http://vbcity.com/forums/p/100559/425591.aspx)

Comment: The XML you are seeing is a persistent recordset. You can use [Recordset.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx) to load that into a different recordset. It's basically a way of serializing the recordset. [Link to Recordset.Save Method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681501(v=vs.85).aspx)